# Specify local IP address in net.DialTCP

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    var localaddr net.TCPAddr
    var remoteaddr net.TCPAddr
    localaddr.IP = net.ParseIP("192.168.1.104")
    localaddr.Port = 6000
    remoteaddr.IP = net.ParseIP("192.168.1.104")
    remoteaddr.Port = 5000

    if localaddr.IP == nil || remoteaddr.IP == nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }

    if _, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", &localaddr, &remoteaddr); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("End")

}
```

If the function specify local IP address, it always reports a run time error "dial tcp 192.168.1.104:5000: An invalid argument was supplied."  I'm confused, should it always be a nil for local IP address ?

go version : 1.1 Beta
OS: Win7 64bit

Tried in go 1.0.3, it seemed OK

Comment: tested with go tip seems to work OK.

Comment: It is quite unusual to want to supply a local address when making a TCP connection, so you probably want to be using `net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.1.104:5000")`.  If you really do want to specify a local address and port, check that the the local address is attached to your local PC and port 6000 isn't in use.  I tried your example under linux and it worked fine so this may be a windows problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go's `net` package, like most such implementations, recognizes port-only syntax for connecting to localhost:

```
:5000
```

is equivalent to

```
<my-ip-address>:5000
```

Thus, you can do:

```
net.Dial("tcp", ":5000")
```

Comment: An example of this in practice: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/proxier_test.go#L41

Answer (score 0):

No, it is ok to have `laddr` argument specified in DialTCP. The problem is that the specified port (6000) is outside of [default Win7 dynamic port range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista) and couldn't be used for outgoing connection. It works on Linux and Mac, actually (if you don't forget to change the IP address to one of your own system).